# grep -v with newlines not behaving as expected

Tags: sh

I'm trying to create a pre-commit trigger for git, I have to use bin/sh for maximum compatibility so please keep to what will work with sh (not bash etc)

I'm not a unix developer, so there is probably something pretty fundamental I'm not grasping here, but I can't seem to discover it.

I have a list of the files in a variable. I want to remove those with certain suffixes.

what I thought would work, does work here: https://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

Input Regex: `^.+(\.auto\.sql|\.sln)$`

```
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
```

`Invert Match (Display Non-Matching Lines)`

Correctly returns

```
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
```

But when I put it into a sh script it doesn't work (I'm using https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online/)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
files="src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
src/blah/Some Other File.sql"

printf "%s" "$files"
numfiles=$( printf '%s' "$files" | grep -c '$' )

printf "\n%s\n" $numfiles

#files=$( printf '%s' "$files" | grep -v "\.auto\.sql") # works but diesn't guarantee end of line
#printf "%s" "$files"

files=$( printf '%s' "$files" | grep -v "^.+(\.auto\.sql|\.sln)$") # doesn't work even though it should match
printf "%s" "$files"
```

returns

```
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
4
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
```

- matching with non-end of line tokens works but the end of line doesn't.
- However -E works fine and finds only the rows I don't want

```
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
4
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels.auto.sql
src/blah/auto/star.LOAD_DimBrandDataLevels_FROM_Mds_mdm_BrandDataConfidence.auto.sql
src/blah/Blah.sln
```

Really not sure what is going on and have exhausted several avenues.

Hopefully someone can shine a bit of light on how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-E, --extended-regexp`:

```
$ printf "%s" "$files" | grep -v -E "^.+(\.auto\.sql|\.sln)$"
src/blah/Some Other File.sql
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and it makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work on jdoodle and sh? If you copy my script in the past and add the -E to the second to last line, you will see I still get all 4 rows returned?

Comment: hmm, well I think it does actually work but for some reason when I copied it back into a new session it didn't and I was getting strange messages.. perhaps something to do with newlines in the string. Thanks